# How to get json data with vars in p5.js

Tags: javascript, api, p5.js

I'm building a dictionary word definition search engine which has a #submit button and #word input. I also have a JSON dictionary([Github link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adambom/dictionary/master/dictionary.json)). I don't know how to select what word definition to use depending on what the user types.

I have already tried putting the input.value() as a var to the json object query:

```
var uInVal = input.value(); 
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = words.uInVal)
```

Can someone help me?

My Code:

```
var words;
var input;

function setup() {
    loadJSON("dictionary.json", gotData);

    var button = select('#submit');
    button.mousePressed(keyDraw);

    input = select('#word');
}

function gotData(data){
    words = data;
}

function keyDraw(){
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML; //This is where the word definition should get printed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please try to work with a [simpler example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Something like this would show your problem in a runnable example:

```
var jsonString = '{"x": 42, "y":100}';
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

This is also easier for you to work with. Now that you have this, I'd google something like "javascript get value from property name" for a ton of results.

But basically, there are two ways to get the value of a property:

```
var xOne = jsonObject.x;
var xTwo = jsonObject['x'];
console.log(xOne);
console.log(xTwo);
```

This is what you're trying to do:

```
var varName = 'x';
var myX = jsonObject.varName;
```

This won't work, because `jsonObject` doesn't have any field named `varName`. Instead, you want to access the `x` field. To do that, you can use bracket `[]` notation:

```
var myX = jsonObject['x'];
```